# Grails not correct redirect

Tags: grails, redirect, groovy, url-mapping

I have a Grails 2.3.4 webapp and when I try to go to an url, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/${myapp}/
```

it always redirects correct how I wanted, but if:

```
 http://localhost:8080/${myapp}
```

without slash I get 404 error(Page not found).

my UrlMappings class:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    //"/"(view: '/error404')
    "/"(action: "someAction", controller: "someController")
    "404"(view: '/error404')
    "500"(view:'/error500')

}
```

}

What I have to do with this?

Comment: Is the 404 from grails or tomacat?

Comment: From grails because there is always my custom page

Comment: That's weird it's working for me (Grails 2.4.4)...